# Cómo puedo obtener cuerpo de correo electrónico cuando es enviado de Iphone usando IMAP php?

Tags: php, imap

Estoy usando Imap php, para tomar los correos con esta función:
`$messages = $imap->getMessages('html');` Y me obtiene los correos correctamente, el problema es cuando el correo que tengo en mi bandeja de entrada, fue enviado desde Iphone, entonces el array trae `null` en el cuerpo del correo.
Si cambio la función de esta manera: `$messages = $imap->getMessages('text');` o así `$messages = $imap->getMessages();`, entonces sí me trae el cuerpo del correo, pero no se ven bien los formatos de los otros mensajes. Hay alguna manera de que me mantenga con el mismo formato html, pero que me traiga la información de cuando es correo enviado desde Iphone ?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué problema tienes en concreto? ¿Qué quieres lograr? ¿Qué depuraciones has hecho?  (puedes usar `var_dump` para depurar)

Comment: No puedo ver el contenido del correo cuando proviene de un Iphone, me trae "null" en el índice "message" ``` array (size=1) 0 =>     array (size=8)
      'subject' => string 'Prueba Jesus asunto' (length=19)    'date' => int 1589487297      'message_id' => string '<05862988-DA0D-4E27-820C-398DC99629CA@icloud.com>' (length=49)     'uid' => int 30     'references' => int 0      'from' =>   array (size=2)          'address' => string 'ejemploprueba@icloud.com' (length=26)        'name' => string Jesus Prueba' (length=13)      'message' => null     'attachments' =>        array (size=0) empty ```

Comment: Puedes pulsar en [edit]  para poner las depuraciones en la pregunta, no en comentarios. Sería bueno también que nos digas si estás usando alguna librería en concreto y si has investigado si la misma no tiene algún método para determinar el sistema o dispositivo que generó el mensaje. Ni siquiera se sabe a qué corresponde ese `var_dump`. Mientras más claridad en la pregunta, mejor. No estamos frente a tu pantalla para conocer tu contexto. Esto también arroja confusión en la pregunta: *entonces sí me trae el cuerpo del correo, pero no se ven bien los formatos de los otros mensajes*